# Make normal tables with doctrine query builder without relations between entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a recurent problem with symfony and doctrine. 
I have to play in the database of another application so I can not set relationships between entity.

When I want to do a left join on some tables, doctrine return a strange format of data like:

```
array[0] => first entity
array[1] => fisrt joined entity
array[2] => second entity
array[3] => second joined entity
...
```

I just would like to have:

```
array[0] => object(id, name, joined entity)....
```

How could I do that.

Below is one of my request:

```
   $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o')->select('o, childs');

       $qb->where('o.unitid = :unitid')
                     ->setParameter('unitid', $unitid);

        $qb->leftJoin(
        '\Entity\Objectconnectors',
        'oc',
        \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
        'oc.parentkey = o.key'
)
           ->leftJoin(
        '\Entity\Objects',
        'childs',
        \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
        'oc.childkey = childs.key'
);





         return  $qb->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Maybe `Native SQL`? http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Comment: For now it's the only solution I found. 
I think that anything is possible with index by, but I didn't manage to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define relationship in a Class to do that, otherwise doctrine could not hydratate data to the entity object because the class doesn't define this associations.

Comment: That's exactly what I could not do

Comment: why you could not do this? Your requested object(id, name, joined entity) has Joined entity definition, you have to write this object to archive that

Comment: I'm scared about this because I cannnot modify this second Database. 
I can access it in read only. 
What will be the concequences if I set doctrine relations ?

Comment: you will not modify databases, only define the association in class.

Comment: remember to check the answer!! :)